# Необходимо объяснить мне массив в задачке по нахождению среднего арифметического

Tags: java, массивы

Я решаю задачку на массив, в которой необходимо найти среднее арифметическое из 4х цифр. Задачку прикреплю ниже. Всё понимаю, за исключением цикла for:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
results = results + nums[i];
System.out.println("Среднее значение равно " + results/4);
```

Почему тут мы к массиву nums[] вставляем i? Как вариант, это для того чтобы привести всё к int, но почему тогда нельзя написать там тип int? И почему тогда в итоге всё равно оно автоматически переводит в double назад? (результат с плавающей точкой).
Если же мы вставляем именно i, то почему тогда к `results = results + nums[i];` не добавляется каждый раз +1? Распишите по пунктам что выполняется, если можно. Заранее спасибо

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double nums[] = {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4};
        double results = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            results = results + nums[i];
        System.out.println("Среднее значение равно " + results/4);
    }
}
```

Среднее значение равно 11.749999999999998

Comment: `i` - целочисленный индекс элемента в массиве. `nums[i]` - вещественное число из массива, с места с номером `i`. Если `i == 2`, то `nums[i] == 12.3`.

Comment: Привет. Так работают массивы в практически любом языке программирования. Конкретно `nums[i]` это получение элемента массива по индексу `i`.  То есть строка `results = results + nums[i];` прибавляет к переменной `result` значение из массива `nums` в ячейке `i`. Попробуй в интернете почитать подробнее, как работают массивы в языках программирования (или сразу на java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nums[i] -->> i = это индекс ячейки в массиве т.е. я беру число из nums[], пример:

```
double nums[] = {10.1, 11.2, 12.3, 13.4};
nums[0] = 10.1
nums[1] = 11.2
nums[2] = 12.3
nums[3] = 13.4
```